# bcrypt hash docker segmentation fault

Tags: node.js, express, docker, bcrypt

I recently set my express app on docker. Unfortunately, I get a **segmentation fault** when I use the hash function of bcrypt. I try also tried hashSync but same problem. I install everything inside the container so I really have no idea what I can do, every works fine without docker ..

Here is my **dockerfile**:

```
FROM *node-app:latest*

COPY package.json /app

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp \
  autoconf \
  automake \
  g++ \
  libpng-dev \
  libtool \
  make \
  nasm \
  python \
  git \
  && npm i \
  && npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source \
  && apk del .gyp

  COPY . /app

  EXPOSE 8080

  CMD ["npm", "run", "start-docker"]
```

Where *node-app* only does:

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
```

Here is the code executed when the **segmentation fault** happens:

```
// also tried with hashSync
const test = bcrypt.hash('PASSWORD', 5).then((err, result) => {
   console.log('err', err);
}).catch ((err) => {
    console.log('err', err);
});
```

Thanks for your help